# Tor Browser Exit Code : 133

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I installed Tor Browser under Ubuntu and that works! but when I restart my computer and when I try to run Tor Browser, Tor shows me this message:
`Tor Browser exited abnormally. Exit code: 133`

What does Code: 133 mean and how may I remedy this problem?